# How do I use Windows Authentication with users in database

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My main goal is using the Windows Authentication to query my custom Users table to use through the web application. I am not sure there is a conventional way of doing this.

I have a predefined Users table and Roles table in a SQL database. How do I use the `User.Identity.Name` to query this Users table and map all the tables data along with the roles to a `ApplicationUser` class that can be further used later in the intranet web application?

I was unable to find anything closely related to what I am after from reading tons of articles. I assume this will be done in the `Startup` class under `ConfigureServices` but am also unsure of that. I need the user to be looked up whenever they navigate to the site for the first time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would go with `ClaimsTransformer` to get user claims. I just will try to show how to get user claims and to handle authorization for Windows Authenticatin.

First create a `ClaimsTransformer` class:

```
public class ClaimsTransformer : IClaimsTransformer
{
    // i assume you have a user service in which you get user info via entity framework
    private readonly IUserService _userService;   
    public ClaimsTransformer(IUserService userService)
    {
         _userService = userService;
    }
    public async Task<ClaimsPrincipal> TransformAsync(ClaimsTransformationContext context)
    {
        var identity = ((ClaimsIdentity)context.Principal.Identity);
        // ... add user claims if required
        var roles = _userService.GetRoles(identity.Name);
        foreach(var role in roles)
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, role));
        }
        return await Task.FromResult(context.Principal);
    }
}
```

Then use it in `Configure` method

```
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        //...
        app.UseClaimsTransformation(async (context) =>
        {
            IClaimsTransformer transformer = context.Context.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IClaimsTransformer>();
            return await transformer.TransformAsync(context);
        });
        //...
    }
```

Unfortunately `User.IsInRole` method doesn't work with `ClaimsTransformer`(if you add role with `ClaimsTransformer`, IsInRole will be false) so you can't use `[Authorize(Roles = "")]` with `ClaimsTransformer`. In this case you can use [Claims Based Authorization](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/security/authorization/claims.html) to handle authotorization.

So finally add below code to ConfigureServices and use `Authorize` attribute:

```
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddSingleton<IClaimsTransformer, ClaimsTransformer>();
        services.AddAuthorization(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("RequireAdministratorRole", policy => policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Role, "Administrator"));
        });
        //...
    }

    [Authorize(Policy = "RequireAdministratorRole")]
    public IActionResult Index() { }
```

Comment: I believe this is exactly what I was after. I will mark correct after I implement and make sure I have no other questions.

Comment: Hi, what about Core 2.2? `UseClaimsTransformation` doesn't exists there anymore :)

Comment: "if you add role with ClaimsTransformer, IsInRole will be false) so you can't use [Authorize(Roles = "")] with ClaimsTransformer." How come? Why is it like that?